# can't exec Exe or batch (lolminer) with node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am going to create a simple lolminer electron apps for my school project.

So I download lolminer and setup the batch file

```
lolMiner.exe --algo ETHASH --pool ethash.unmineable.com:3333 --user DOGE:DK32SaiLzRn9npSwxzCoCY8BLbHMAqiUVV.Desktop --ethstratum ETHPROXY
pause
```

then I try to run the batch with this code

```
require('child_process').exec('cmd /c mining.bat', function(err, stdout, stderr){
  // …you callback code may run here…
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

but it return nothing.
and I try to insert arguments but no luck.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('lolMiner.exe', ['--algo','ETHASH','--pool','ethash.unmineable.com:3333','--user','DOGE:DK32SaiLzRn9npSwxzCoCY8BLbHMAqiUVV.Desktop'], (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log(stdout);
});
```

But this does return something

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('lolMiner.exe', ['--algo','ETHASH'], (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log(stdout);
});
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|   _       _ __  __ _                   _   ____  ___    |
|  | | ___ | |  \/  (_)_ __   ___ _ __  / | |___ \( _ )   |
|  | |/ _ \| | |\/| | | '_ \ / _ \ '__| | |   __) / _ \   |
|  | | (_) | | |  | | | | | |  __/ |    | |_ / __/ (_) |  |
|  |_|\___/|_|_|  |_|_|_| |_|\___|_|    |_(_)_____\___/   |
|                                                         |
|              This software is for mining                |
|              Ethash, Etchash                            |
|              Equihash 144/5, 192/7, 210/9               |
|              BeamHash I, II, III                        |
|              ZelHash     (EquihashR 125/4/0)            |
|              Cuck(ar)oo 29                              |
|              Cuckaroo   30 CTX                          |
|              Cuckatoo   31/32                           |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|              Made by Lolliedieb, May 2021               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I still can't make it run.
My idea is to let user input their wallet address, choose their algo and run the lolminer.

is this idea work or I can't make it done with node.js

Comment: without nodejs, what should happen when you run: lolMiner.exe ... ?

Comment: it should start mining
https://imgshare.io/image/screenshot-2021-05-22-005252.p8MmZg

Comment: if you expect that nodejs will open a cmd ui with lolminer log, this never will happen. Try to research how start lolminer in detached or background mode. Then, use the exact commands in nodejs